# Stream position with JsonTextReader in Json.Net

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm using Json.Net's fast `JsonTextReader` to parse large JSON documents.  There are portions of the JSON I want to skip and hand off to another process to parse.  `JsonTextReader.Skip()` works great for quickly skipping over a section, but I haven't found a way to copy the "raw" string JSON that I skipped so I can pass it somewhere else.  If I could get the stream offset position of the JsonTextReader before and after I called `Skip()`, maybe I could scan the document stream to pull out the parts I want, but I haven't found a way to do this either.

I'm able to use LINQ to JSON to do what I want

```
JObject.Parse(myDocument)["MySkippedSection"].ToString()
```

but it's several times slower than using `JsonTextReader` and speed is very important for my application.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: In documentation there seem to be two properties `LineNumber` and `LinePosition`. Can you use them? http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextReader.htm  Or use method `ReadAsString` which will read next token and then somehow use method `SetToken` to move back to it and then use `Skip`. But this considerations are purely based on documentation and I'm not sure they will be applicable in your situation.

Comment: @steavy: I wasn't sure how to use `LineNumber` and `LinePosition` to seek into a stream since these will vary depending on how many `\r\n` there are in a document... it may be possible with a `TextReader` though.  I tried using ReadAsString and ReadAsBytes, but I can't seem to use these for reading subsections of JSON - they expect actual string values and byte arrays.